# Difference in the interfacing with Bluetooth on android 2.2 and android 6

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth

I made a code to scan near by bluetooth devices for the api level 8. But now when I am going to use the same app for the api level 23 it just failed to scan. Apart from bluetooth activity other things are working fine. Can any one tell where the job goes wrong?
I attached a sample code which works on api 8 but not on api 23

```
public class MyBluetoothScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button bt,bt_count;
ListView listView;
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesArray;
IntentFilter filter;
BroadcastReceiver receiver;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
ArrayList<String> pairedDevices;
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices;
int count=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_bluetooth_scan);

    bt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bT_scan2);
    bt.setTransformationMethod(null);

    bt_count=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_count);
    bt_count.setTransformationMethod(null);

    bt_count.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Count: "+count,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    });




    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewscan);

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);

    if(!btAdapter.isEnabled()){
        turnOnBT();
    }


    init();

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            newScan();
        }
    });


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(btAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            }
            if(!listAdapter.getItem(i).contains("Paired")){
                try {
                    BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(i);
                    pairDevice(selectedDevice);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    newScan();
                }
                catch (Exception e){}
            }
            else{
                BluetoothDevice selectedDevice = devices.get(i);
                Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),BtIns.class);
                intent.putExtra("MAC",selectedDevice.getAddress());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void newScan(){
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"New Scan Start",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

    listAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,0);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    btAdapter.startDiscovery();
}
private void getPairedDevices() {
    devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(devicesArray.size()>0){
        for(BluetoothDevice device:devicesArray){
            pairedDevices.add(device.getName());

        }
    }
}

void turnOnBT(){
    Intent intent =new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivity(intent);
}

void init(){

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String action = intent.getAction();

            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"new br: "+action,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){

                pairedDevices=new ArrayList<String>();
                getPairedDevices();
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Dev: "+device.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                devices.add(device);
                String s = "";
                for(int a = 0; a < pairedDevices.size(); a++){
                    if(device.getName().equals(pairedDevices.get(a))){
                        //append
                        s = "(Paired)";
                        break;
                    }
                }

                listAdapter.add(device.getName()+" "+s+" "+"\n"+device.getAddress());

            }
            else if(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)){
                if(btAdapter.getState() == btAdapter.STATE_OFF){
                    turnOnBT();
                }
            }


        }
    };
}

private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Exception: "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Registration",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanning for Bluetooth or Wi-Fi devices on API 23 and above requires that you first be granted the Location permission. In addition, you must also ensure that Location is enabled in Settings.

Using Google Play Services, you can check the Location settings and request for them to be enabled using the `SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings()` API, e.g.

```
final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);

final LocationSettingsRequest request = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
        .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
        .setAlwaysShow(true)
        .setNeedBle(true)
        .build();

mPendingResult = SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mClient, request);
```

See: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi

For requesting permission, you first need to declare the permission in your manifest, and request the permission before scanning.  See the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I set the permission using <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE"/> but still the issue present

Comment: That's not the correct permission -- one of `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is required. You also must request it at runtime for API 23 and above (as described in the documentation)

Comment: still the problem remains same. the discovery start and consequently finished but out come is no device found.

Comment: I got your point but just don't work. Can you give an complete example on that.